# How to start Webpack and fixtures in Prod

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, webpack

I would like to know how to start Webpack to start build my css/js files but also launching my Fixtures in Prod?

I have already done several small php and symfony projects but without using Fixtures and even Webpack (I used the classic system for css & js), so I tell myself that when I go to put my site in prod I would need to start this command for my site to work. 
I use these commands for my site in localhost

```
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
yarn encore dev --watch
```

but how do I go about making these orders when my site goes online?

edit :
webpack.config.js :

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
.addEntry('style', './assets/js/style.js')
```

twig :

```
css :
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('style') }}
js:
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('style') }}
```

my public folder before and after "yarn build"

[image]
[image]

and my rendering before and after yarn build:

[image]
[image]

this is just a page of the site that I could show, but the compilation disassembles all the pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

> yarn encore production

I believe Fixtures works on prod like on dev environment, just change db config.

Comment: thank you, so i just need to run this command after add the project in the server? for the fixtures how to run the command?

Comment: Loading the fixtures truncates the database, so unless it's just static content I wouldn't advise it! Use migrations instead. If it's indeed static, you could explore [alternatives](https://github.com/symplify/symfony-static-dumper)

Comment: @threeside thank you, just a last think, when i run the command "yarn build" all my css is like "deformed", its normal?

Comment: @alternatives yeah i know, its a new database i have nothing yet so its not a problem

Comment: @Imrickjames yes encore minimize css and js and put all your css in one files. The time to load multiple css (not minimize) are a big, so it's the job of Encore to reduce all in one file and all should work as expected.

Comment: i wanted to say my design is not same before and after i run "yarn encore production", its look like deformed

Comment: Check if distant resources are correctly load, and use developper toolas on firefox or chrome to search which css are not load correctly

Comment: @threeside please i edit my question, i still can't resolve it

Comment: Can you give your entire "webpack.config.js" and  "assets/js/app.js" files please ?

Comment: sorry to bein late, everything is good now after cleaned my css, maybe i had some bad configuration